# How can I use lodash max against a jQuery array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, lodash

I'm trying to get the max rows out of two tables. What am I doing wrong? maxRows ends up being a tbody jQuery element and not the max property value.  Any ideas? I've tried the pluck syntax as well as the long form and both seem to return the element and not the max value. See [Lodash max](http://lodash.com/docs#max)

```
var tables = $('.ui-datepicker-group table tbody');
var maxRows = _.max(tables, 'childElementCount');
```

Thanks for any tips or tricks here. I'm obviously doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the `tbody` element with the maximum number of `tr`'s then

```
var tables = $('.ui-datepicker-group table tbody');
var maxRows = _.max(tables, function(el){
    return $(el).children().length
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/AqcZ2/)

If you want the number or rows then

```
var tables = $('.ui-datepicker-group table tbody');
var maxRows = _.max(tables.map(function(_, el){
    return $(el).children().length
}));
console.log(maxRows)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/BQTp7/)

Comment: Yes this is correct. I am getting the object back with the max value. That works as expected.

Comment: One little caveat is that Array.map isn't available to IE8, only IE9 and up. Unfortunately this app needs to work in IE8. No worries I certainly have enough info to make it work as designed.

Comment: @Hcabnettek it is not using `Arrray.map()` it is using [.map](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

Answer (score 0):

It's working correctly; it simply returns the item with the max property, not just the property value.

Sorry, it was my mistake.